# How to use Random.nextInt()?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I try to get random integer but i get nullpointerexception. I want to get ArrayList with first element what i add at the beggining and this is correct. Next elements i want to get three random String from answersdata[10]. I checked that in answersdata are elements what i want.
answersdata is String[]
I have error in this line:

```
nr1 = rand.nextInt(10);
```

All code of this method:

```
private void set_answer(int nrquestion) {
int nr1, nr2, nr3;  
answers.add(answersdata[nrquestion]);

do{
    nr1 = rand.nextInt(10);
}while(nr1==nrquestion);

answers.add(answersdata[nr1]);  

do{
    nr2 = rand.nextInt(10);
}while(nr2==nrquestion|| nr2==nr1);

answers.add(answersdata[nr2]);

do{
    nr3 = rand.nextInt(10);
}while(nr3==nrquestion|| nr3==nr1 || nr3==nr2);

answers.add(answersdata[nr3]);


Collections.shuffle(answers);
}
```

When i write static number its working for example:

```
nr1 = 5;
```

Comment: Where do you get null pointer exception ? on which line of code?

Comment: Have you initialised `rand`?

Comment: here is null pointer exception `nr1 = rand.nextInt(10);` and yes i init it `private Random rand;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you forgot to initialize rand with a Random object.

Random rand = new Random(); //before trying to make calls on rand

Comment: thx, i had `private Random rand;` when i changed to `private Random rand = new Random();` it start working

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps showing a quick method would explain how it works better than an actual explanation:

```
public int generateRandomNumberBetween(int min, int max){
    return min + new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1);
}
```

The method above will generate a number between [min, max] (inclusive). It is encouraged you create a constant `Random` instance somewhere so you don't have to keep creating a new 1 upon each method invocation.